# The most efficient solution for finding the minimum value

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have a list of Sugar. The Sugar class has two field: price and weight:

```
data class Sugar(var price: Double, var weight: Double)
```

And I need to find max/min value by this fields.
I found two ways to do this. The first way is to use a ready-made solution:

```
        val minPrice = list.minBy { it.price }?.price
        val maxPrice = list.maxBy { it.price }?.price

        val minWeight = list.minBy { it.weight }?.weight
        val maxWeight = list.maxBy { it.weight }?.weight
```

Second way:

```
        var minPrice = list.first().price
        var maxPrice = list.first().price

        var minWeight = list.first().weight
        var maxWeight = list.first().weight

        for (i in 1..list.size) {
            if (list[i].price < minPrice) {
                minPrice = list[i].price
            }
            if (list[i].price > maxPrice) {
                maxPrice = list[i].price
            }
            if (list[i].weight < minWeight) {
                minWeight = list[i].weight
            }
            if (list[i].weight > maxWeight) {
                maxWeight = list[i].weight
            }
        }
```

Both solutions work, but I need to find the most efficient one. Please, tell me which method is better to use, or perhaps there is a more efficient solution for this purpose.

Comment: What do you think it the most efficient? Consider how many loop iterations the first would require compared to the second. You can also always do some profiling to get an indication of which performs better in practice. Regardless, this type of optimization is probably overkill unless you're having some performance problems.

Comment: There's also `maxOf`, which would boil your first example down to lines like `val maxWeight = list.maxOf { it.weight }`. However, it won't necessarily be of better performance.

Comment: I think Kotlin methods are not optimized for efficiency, binary sort is considered an optimal sorting algorithm. Search for that and try to implement it, or use a library that has it.

Comment: @cutiko why would you use a sorting algorithm for just finding a max or min value?

Comment: @Joffrey because binary search needs to know the value, so you can't use that. With binary sorting, you get the first or last, and then that is min or max. The complexity is `Log(N)`, but finding minimum by iteration is using the methods I have read and recall do an iteration will always be, `N`. Linear is more than log, since OP emphasis is "efficient solution". That is why.

Comment: @cutiko could you please point me to a resource about this algorithm showing it's O(log(n))? All I could find is n.log(n) comparisons and mentions of quadratic behaviour, but maybe it's not the same algo. Also, I would love to see how it's possible to sort N elements without even looking once at each of them

Comment: But in any case, all the modifications of the array you sort are likely wasting a lot compared to a linear pass, and the OP probably doesn't want to destroy the initial list. It's not just about comparisons.

Comment: @cutiko The complexity of a binary search is O(log(n)) on a _sorted_ list. But here we have a list that's (presumably) unsorted. (It certainly can't be sorted by both price _and_ weight simultaneously!) So to do each binary search, first you'd need to sort the list, which has a complexity of at least O(n·log(n)) — a lot worse than the O(n) of a simple scan.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the first solution iterates over the list for four times, while the second one iterates only once. So second option is performant. You can rewrite the solution in functional way

```
data class Metrics(val minPrice: Double = 0.0, val maxPrice: Double = 0.0, val minWeight: Double = 0.0, val maxWeight: Double = 0.0)

val (minPrice, maxPrice, minWeight, maxWeight) = list.fold(Metrics()){ acc, sugar ->
    Metrics(
      minPrice = min(sugar.price, acc.minPrice),
      maxPrice = max(sugar.price, acc.maxPrice),
      minWeight = min(sugar.weight, acc.minWeight),
      maxWeight = max(sugar.weight, acc.maxWeight)
    )
  }
```

Comment: Note that `premature optimization is the root of all evil`.